# Perl error in grepping array

Tags: perl

I have written a sub procedure in perl to check whether if  my string array contains  a particular value.

```
sub check_if_entity_exists() {

    my $entity      = shift;
    my @entityarray = @_;

    print "my entity to be checked $entity  \n";
    print "entity array before change  @entityarray : \n";

    join(" ", map { s/^\s*|\s*$//g; $_ } @entityarray);

    print " array after change @entityarray \n";

    my $status = "FALSE";

    if (grep { $_ eq $entity } @entityarray) {
        $status = "TRUE";
        return $status;
    }
    else {
        return $status;
    }
}
```

In the  above code `@entityarray` = xyz.com
`$entity` = xyz.com
Since entity is there in entity array i expect to set to true but flow is going to false

Output log:
my entity to be checked xyz.com
entity array before change  xyz.com : 
 array after change xyz.com

Comment: It works for me (given that you remove the prototype from the sub). How do you call the sub?

Comment: How are you calling this function, because I tried it with `'xyz.com'` as per your exmple and it returned `"TRUE"`. So it worked for me.

Comment: @stevenl and Quick Joe, presumably the two differ in leading or trailing whitespace, which is not showing up in the question.  The removal of whitespace is the part of the code that is failing.

Comment: I am calling like this check_if_entity_exists( @result_list_instance, $instance_to_be_checked );

Comment: I was calling it reverse thanks

Comment: Please take note of the other advice offered in the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an empty prototype for your `check_if_entity_exists` subroutine. That insists that there must be no parameters to this subroutine, which is wrong. You should *never* use prototypes in Perl - they work differently from prototyps in other langauges and are meant for something very specific.

You are also using `map` in void context, and `join` generates a string that is immediately discarded. You should *always* have

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

at the top of *all* your programs, which would have told you

> Useless use of join in void context

And you should write the `map` loop as

```
for (@entityarray) {
  s/^\s+//;
  s/\s+\z//;
}
```

Other than that, your code does what it should for me. If I call it like this

```
my @entityarray = ('    xyz.com    ');
my $entity = 'xyz.com';

print check_if_entity_exists($entity, @entityarray);
```

**output**

```
my entity to be checked xyz.com  
entity array before change      xyz.com     : 
 array after change xyz.com 
TRUE
```

It would be better to write this using the `first` function from `List::Util`, like this

```
use List::Util 'first';

sub check_if_entity_exists {
  my $entity = shift;
  defined(first { /^\s*\Q$entity\E\s*$/ } @_) ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE';
}
```

Comment: I am calling like this check_if_entity_exists( @result_list_instance, $instance_to_be_checked );

Comment: But your code pulls `$entity` from the *beginning* of the array, so you should reverse those two paremeters. Take the prototype off the subroutine definition anyway.